# Primefaces não localiza componentes de Panel e DataTable

Tags: mysql, ajax, jsf, primefaces, hibernate

Estou fazendo um trabalho em que utilizo Primefaces + Ajax + Hibernate. Tenho uma tela para incluir/alterar um cliente que deveria abrir numa modal toda vez que o usuário clicasse no botão. E nesse mesmo código tenho um dataTable para mostrar todos os clientes. No entanto, por algum motivo, todas as vezes aparece o mesmo erro:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Cannot find component with expression "infosCliente" referenced from "j_idt9".
```

O mesmo se dá com o dataTable. Parece que o Primefaces não "localiza" esses componentes na página. Esta é a minha view:

index.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:pm="http://primefaces.org/mobile">

    <f:view contentType="text/html">
        <h:head>
            <f:facet name="first">
                <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
                <title>PrimeFaces</title>
            </f:facet>
            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="dot-luv/skin.css"/>
        </h:head>

        <h:body>
            <p:layout fullPage="true">
                <p:layoutUnit position="left" header="Atividades" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">
                    <h:form prependId="false">
                        <p:commandLink value="Novo Cliente" actionListener="#{clientes.prepararAdicionarClientes}" update="infosCliente" oncomplete="dialogGerCliente.show()"/>
                    </h:form>
                </p:layoutUnit>
                <p:layoutUnit position="center">
                    <h1>Gerenciador de Clientes</h1>
                    <br/>
                    <h:form prependId="false">
                        <p:dataTable id="tabela" var="cliente" value="#{clientes.listarClientes}">
                            <p:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="Nome"/>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{cliente.nome}" />
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="Endereço"/>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{cliente.endereco}"/>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="Telefone"/>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{cliente.telefone}"/>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="Data de Nascimento"/>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{cliente.dtnascimento}"/>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="E-mail"/>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{cliente.email}"/>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="Alterar"/>
                                </f:facet>
                                <p:commandButton actionListener="#{clientes.alterarClientes}" value="Alterar" update="infosCliente" oncomplete="dialogGerCliente.show()"/>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="Excluir"/>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:commandLink action="#{clientes.excluirCliente}" value="Excluir"/>
                            </p:column>
                        </p:dataTable>
                    </h:form>
                </p:layoutUnit>
            </p:layout>

            <p:dialog header="Gerência de Clientes" widgetVar="dialogGerCliente"  resizable="false" modal="true" showEffect="slide" width="500">
                <h:form prependId="false">
                    <h:panelGrid id="infosCliente" columns="2" style="margin-bottom:10px">

                        <h:outputLabel for="nome" value="Nome:" />
                        <h:inputText id="nome" value="#{clientes.clientes.nome}"/>

                        <h:outputLabel for="endereco" value="Endereço:" />
                        <h:inputText id="endereco" value="#{clientes.clientes.endereco}"/>

                        <h:outputLabel for="telefone" value="Telefone:" />
                        <h:inputText id="telefone" value="#{clientes.clientes.telefone}"/>

                        <h:outputLabel for="dtnascimento" value="Data de Nascimento" />
                        <h:inputText id="dtnascimento" value="#{clientes.clientes.dtnascimento}"/>

                        <h:outputLabel for="email" value="E-mail:" />
                        <h:inputText id="email" value="#{clientes.clientes.email}"/>

                        <p:commandButton update="tabela" oncomplete="dialogGerCliente.hide();" actionListener="#{clientes.adicionarClientes}" value="Inserir Cliente"/>
                        <p:commandButton update="tabela" oncomplete="dialogGerCliente.hide();" actionListener="#{clientes.alterarClientes}" value="Alterar Cliente"/>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </h:form>
            </p:dialog>
        </h:body>
    </f:view>
</html>
```

Se eu retirar infosCliente e tabela (os ids), a página exibe a tabela com todos os clientes cadastrados e dá até para excluir, porém o alterar não funciona e não aparece o botão para a modal de inserção/alteração.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Às vezes o primefaces não consegue localizar o componente quando está dentro de uma dialog ou uma tab, por exemplo. Tente alterar o update para:

```
<p:commandLink value="Novo Cliente" actionListener="#{clientes.prepararAdicionarClientes}" update="#{p:component('infosCliente')}" oncomplete="dialogGerCliente.show()"/>
```